# Less extend from imported file not working vs mixin from imported file

Tags: css, less, mixins, extend

With the following two files `a.less` and `b.less`:

`a.less`:

```
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

and `b.less`:

```
@import "a.less"

.testA:extend(.red) {
}

.testB {
    .red;
}
```

The result for `b.css` is:

```
.testA {}
.testB {
    background: red;
}
```

Why does extend not work with the imported mixin/class definition for `.testA`? Is there a limitation on the extend syntax that requires the extended definition to be present in the same file, i.e. **is this expected behavior?**

*Note that `.testA` gets compiled correctly if I move the `.red` mixin to `b.less`.*

*Edit: I am using the less binary precompiler, version 1.6.1*

*Edit: To be absolutely sure about typos and as I don't think there's a online service that allows several less files and imports, download the example source [here](http://johannesneumeier.com/static/less-test.zip) - as a matter of fact `.testa{}` won't get rendered at all, but `b.css` naturally has a `.red` class defined.*

*Edit: When I compile from bash the extend works correctly, but using the [less.app GUI](http://incident57.com/less/) or compiling via my [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (with the same command as from bash) or via a [local file watcher](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) the extend does not get included correctly - could this somehow have to do with where the binary gets called from?*

Comment: It should. What Less version do you test with?

Comment: just checking, but maybe it is a typo - at least in the above example you are using `:extends` ... it should be `:extend` (without the trailing `s`). Otherwise, as @seven-phases-max says, it should normally work.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Typo in the question only, fixed it, but the problem remains.

Comment: As @seven-phases-max asked, what version of LESS and is it the less.js or php version or what that you are using to compile?

Comment: @ScottS, & seven-phases-max, see updated question, version 1.6.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with 1.6.1 (it complies your example as expected). Is this actually the code you test? (just guessing, considering a few typos it has, e.g. missing `;` after `@import`). I.e. there must be something else that causes the problem.

Comment: Just for example: if `.red` is defined as `.red() {background: red;}` the result will be exactly as you get (those parens are easy to miss) - yet again, just trying to guess...

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for your suggestions. I added a link to my source files to the question for download. It also includes the generated css files, with `b.css` missing the extend'ed .testa

Comment: Tried your zip. Strange it still compiles fine for me. Btw., I see your css files are minimized, is this Less built-in `--clean-css` option or some other minifier? (built-in `--clean-css` gives me correct result but I may have different `clean-css` version installed).

Comment: This gets interesting. When I compile from bash the extend works correctly, but using the [less.app GUI](http://incident57.com/less/) or compiling via my IDE (with the same command as from bash) or via a [local file watcher](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) the extend does not get included correctly - could this somehow have to do with where the binary gets called from?

Comment: "less.app" ships with Less 1.3.3 which does not support `extend`. And for the rest it looks like you have two different lessc versions hanging around (1.3.3 and 1.6.1) called from your console/IDE... 1.3.3 does not throw error for `:extend(...)` because it's treated as valid CSS selector (but then eliminated from the output since the ruleset is empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @seven-phases-max pointed out, the problem is a differing version of the less preprocessor shipped in the GUI tool, which does not have the `:extend` feature.